# Why does this parameter expansion replacement fail in bash 4.2 but work in 5.1?

Tags: bash, glob, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to port some code from bash 5.1 to 4.2.46. One function which tries to strip color codes from a specifically formatted string stopped working.

This is a sample string `text` in such format. I turn on extended globbing for this.

```sh
text="$(printf -- "%b%s%b" "\[\e[31m\]" "hello" "\[\e[0m\]")"
shopt -s extglob
```

In bash 5.1, this parameter expansion works to remove all the color codes and escape characters

```sh
bash-5.1$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[/}"
31m\]hello0m\]
bash-5.1$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[+([0-9])/}"
m\]hellom\]
bash-5.1$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[+([0-9])m$'\]'/}"
hello
```

In bash 4.2.46, I start getting a different behavior as I build up the parameter expansion.

```sh
bash-4.2.46$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[/}"
\31m\]hello\0m\]
bash-4.2.46$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[+([0-9])/}"
\[\]hello\[\]  ## no longer matches because `+([0-9])` doesn't follow `\[`
```

The difference comes from this line: `echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[/}"`

```
bash-5.1:    31m\]hello0m\]
bash-4.2.46: \31m\]hello\0m\]
```

Here's what `printf "%q" "${text//$'\[\e'\[/}"` shows:

```
bash-5.1:    31m\\\]hello0m\\\]
bash-4.2.46: \\31m\\\]hello\\0m\\\]
```

Where is the extra `\` coming from in 4.2.26?

Even when I try to remove it, the pattern stops matching:

```sh
bash-4.2.46$ echo "${text//$'\[\e'\[\\/}"
\[\]hello\[\]  ## no longer matches because `\\` doesn't follow `\[`
```

I'm guessing there may be a bug related to parameter expansion, backslash escaping, and extended globbing.

I am aiming to write code that works on bash 4.0 onward, so I'm looking for a workaround primarily. An explanation (bug report, etc.) to why the behavior difference happens would be great, though.

Comment: I tested this in more versions of bash. The error (?) is reproducible in 4.0.0(1) and 3.2.57(1) too. In 4.4.0(1) the expansion works just as it does in 5.

Comment: All these years I never realized you could combine those. Thanks for the suggestion! Edited the question, though it's still an eyesore. :')

Comment: I think 5.0 is worth having the minimal version instead of 4.

Comment: It's difficult to trace the changes unfortunately. Maybe consider asking about it through `bashbug`.

Comment: In the end my workaround was to just surround the escape characters with an invisible sentinel character (unit separator) when I generate the colored text, then the stripping code just finds those sentinel characters and rips out the escape characters, leaving the real text.

Comment: I agree about having 5.x+ but unfortunately stuck on 4.x in some enterprise environments (CentOS…)

Comment: The thought was it could inspire a workaround. But I ended up going in a completely different direction. I still like to understand these kinds of things as I work on very old, disparate versions of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be parsing `$'...'` inside `${test//<here>}` when inside `"` quotes.

```
$ test='f() { "${text//\[$'\''\e'\''\[+([0-9])/}"; }; printf "%q\n" "$(declare -f f)"'; echo -n 'bash4.1 '; docker run bash:4.1 bash -c "$test" ; echo -n 'bash5.1 '; bash -c "$test"
bash4.1 $'f () \n{ \n    "${text//\\[\E\\[+([0-9])/}"\n}'
bash5.1 $'f () \n{ \n    "${text//\\[\'\E\'\\[+([0-9])/}"\n}'
```

Just use a variable.

```
esc=$'\e'
echo "${text//\\\[$esc\[+([0-9])/}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a bug in bash. By bisecting the [available versions](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), I found that 4.2.53(1)-release was the last version with this bug. Version 4.3.0(1)-release fixed the problem.

The [list of changes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) mentions a few bug fixes in this direction. Maybe it was one of below bugfixes:

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.3-alpha,
> and the previous version, bash-4.2-release.
> [...]
> zz. When using the pattern substitution word expansion, bash now runs the
> replacement string through quote removal, since it allows quotes in that
> string to act as escape characters.  This is not backwards compatible, so
> it can be disabled by setting the bash compatibility mode to 4.2.
> [...]
> eee. Fixed a logic bug that caused extended globbing in a multibyte locale to
> cause failures when using the pattern substititution word expansions.

#### Workaround

Instead of using parameter expansions with extglobs, use bash pattern matching with actual regexes (available in bash 3.0.0 and higher):

```
text=$'\[\e[31m\]hello\[\e[0m\]'
while [[ "$text" =~ (.*)$'\[\e['[0-9]*'m\]'(.*) ]]; do
  text="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
echo "$text"
```

or rely on an external (but posix standarized) tool like `sed`:

```
text=$'\[\e[31m\]hello\[\e[0m\]'
text=$(sed $'s#\\\[\e[[0-9]*m\\\]##g' <<< "$text")
echo "$text"
```

Comment: `When using the pattern substitution word expansion, bash now runs the replacement string through quote removal..` my guess this is this.